# Why is it not allowed to have default arguments on function declaration and definition?

Tags: c++

so why is it not allowed to have default arguments on the function declaration and implementation? Wouldnt this be more readable for the implementer and the user of the function?

Is there a special reason why this is not allowed, or why the compiler or linker cant handle this?

Best regards

Comment: And if the user uses the wrong values? Or changes one and not the other? It is just more work for the compiler/linker for no gain whatsoever. Default values are only used at the call site, so having them only in the declaration is enough.

Comment: Because onlythe declaration matters.  Default arguments tell the compiler what arguments to insert at call sites.  If default arguments were allowed at the implementation, now you introduce a problem where the implementation is misleading if it uses different values than the declaration used by the caller.

Comment: Technically they could have allowed it, for sure, and e.g. made it an error to have it be different between declaration and implementation. I don't know why they didn't - at a guess it was probably just deemed an unnecessary complication.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError  the compiler couldn't necessarily detect the error. The declaration may not even be included

Comment: The default arguments are filled in at the caller's callsite.  So the callsite has to be able to see what the default arguments are.  Which is why they go in the header file for the function declarations.  (This is a bit brittle, because if a default argument value changes, everything impacted has to be recompiled.  Using an overload thunk function and passing in the default values internally means that dependent callers do not have to be recompiled.  Only important for larger projects.)

Comment: Thanks guys! So i thought that if i call a function foo(); The compiler replaces it with foo(defaultArgument); for example, if foo is declared with a default argument. And therefore i thought that the linker should not have a problem to link it with the definition, even though the definition has also a default argument, but im wrong. Thanks for the explanations.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, it is just that we cannot have, in the same scope, 2 declarations with a (common parameter with a) [default argument](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments):

```
void foo(int = 42);
void foo(int = 42); // Error.
```

and definition acts also as declaration.

if your definition doesn't include the header with the declaration,
you might have default in definition too.

Notice that `default` is not part of the signature, but should anyway is the same (by scope) for each translation unit (for inline functions, and also for non-inline functions since C++20 (but some default can be omitted)).

I don't know the why of those rules though.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real reason except that the committee decided so and they apparently like to show their power by torturing millions of programmers this way.

Ok... may be this is not true but in my opinion it's a more logical explanation of why this is forbidden that anything I've read about the issue.

Note that `g++` with `-fpermissive` allows default to be specified both in declaration and in implementation IF THE VALUES ARE THE SAME and gives an error if they are different.
This is the way IMO it should be in the standard, but it's not.

Because no.

PS: Don'y try to read too much into logical reasons about the rules of C++. Many times there are reasons, sometimes there are just poor justifications of a sad incident that must stay in forever for backward compatibility, sometimes there is no reason at all... it's just the way it is. This, added to the complexity of C++ and the concept of Undefined Behavior, is in my opinion why experimenting with C++ doesn't work well and you need to actually read the standard rules. Being smart doesn't help if you're experimenting, because the "correct" answer is often the wrong one. There's no way you can guess what was the decision taken in that rainy day at the committee meeting.